# Python binary file is truncated

Tags: python, file-io, binary, bmp

As part of an image manipulation program, I'm attempting to write binary files with python 3.9.1. The issue is that the files my script creates are truncated before they should be. My script is as follows:

```py
f = open('outfile', 'wb')
r = 255
for g in range(255): 
    for b in range(255):
        f.write(bytes([r,g,b]))
f.close()
```

`outfile` gets created, but is consistently 1533 bytes shorter than expected (195075 bytes vs the expected 196608) and I can't figure out why! The size on disk is exactly the latter number, but opening it with a hex editor shows that those 1.5 kb are definitely missing. This is on Windows 10 64-bit if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question... My loops are off by one ‍♂️